# Assembly Language .asciiz Error on Mac QtSpim

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I am having some issues with importing a text file into QtSpim.  The following is the exact file I am entering.

Program 2

```
    .data 
    BYTE1:      .byte 0xAD
    BYTE2:      .byte 0xDE
    MYNAME:     .asciiz “SamW”
    WORD1:      .word 0
    WORD2:      .word 0
    WORD3:      .word 0
    WORD4:      .word 0
    WORD5:  .word 0

    .text
    .globl main

    main:
        la $t0, BYTE1
        add $s0, $zero, $t0
```

Importing this into QtSpim works fine as long as I don't have the 4th line included with the .asciiz statement.  Every time that I try to run it with that statement in it I am getting this error message.

[image: Error Message]

If anyone could shed some light on what is going on here that would be great.  I have tried creating a .txt file in both text edit as well as word and then saving it as a .s or .asm and no matter what I get the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes like this " " instead of “ ”.
"SamW" instead of “SamW”.

Comment: @Samuel Make sure it's the double quotes (") and not the simple (') repeated 2 times.

Comment: I just confirmed that's not the issue.

Comment: Okay so I just went onto my teachers example and copy and pasted his quotation marks into my document and it's working now.  I don't understand how are there two different types of quotation marks?  Can I change something on my computer so that I don't have this issue any more or am I going to have to copy and paste the double quotes symbol ever time.  I am not using 2 apostrophes I am using the quotation marks on my computer and they don't work.  SO weird.

Comment: Okay I figured it out, it seems like someone posted a topic regarding this issue at another point but in a more general way.  Apparently on Mavericks one has to disable the "Smart Quotes" feature through system preferences>keyboard>text>"disable smart quotes." Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's the way to change the type of quotes.